# adding series from existing highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have made a chart using highcharts, and i want to redraw my high chart, but this line of code is confusing me and not allowing me to add existing data. this adds random data, but what i want is to add data from the javascript...

```
// Add the new series.
chart.addSeries({ data: Highcharts.map(Array(12), Math.random) }, false);
```

other code:

```
 $(".test").change(function() {
    var value = this.getAttribute("value");
    while (chart.series.length > 0) {
        chart.series[0].remove(true);
    }
    if (value == 'a') {
        loadA(chart);
    } else if (value == 'b') {
        chart.xAxis[0].update({categories: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue']});
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall4',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#FF00FF',  
            data:[100, 280, 300, 490, 670, 900]             
        });            
        chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "Raw" });
    } else if (value == 'c') {
        chart.xAxis[0].update({categories: ['Oranges',  'Pears', 'Pinneaples',  'other']});
```

this is the Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VnCgx/9/

want something like

```
  chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
});
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the browser console to see which errors are produced?

Comment: want something like 

  chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
    });

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what is it that you want done. If it is updating the first series, it is trivial (see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VnCgx/12/) ). Otherwise, please explain better.

Comment: yeah that works, but i need it to connect it from vb.net so the data can be taken from the server, so i need to put that fuction in RegisterClientScriptBlock , any ideas how

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a member of the .net family. But if this is your issue, you should tag your question VB.Net, accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what you need

```
function redraw(chart) {

// Delete all the series.
/*
while (chart.series.length > 0) {
    chart.series[0].remove(false);
}
*/

// Add the new series.

 chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5,   106.4]);
chart.redraw();
```

Comment: setData() contains redraw(), so you don't need to call redraw() again. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData()